# Magento2 cannot override class Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped?

Tags: overrides, model, magento-2.1, grouped-products

I was trying to override the above class `(Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped)`

Below is my `app/code/Best/CustomGrouped/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" type="Best\CustomGrouped\Model\Product\Type\Grouped"/>
</config>
```

And below is the model class `app/code/Best/CustomGrouped/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php`

```
<?php
namespace Best\CustomGrouped\Model\Product\Type;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped
{
    public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I debug through the code, but it still goes to the core class rather using my overridden one. I do not want to use a plugin. I just want to know what am I missing here when overriding the class `Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. : I already checked with clearing the cache, generation etc. in var folder. But it didn't worked. I'm using Magento EE 2.1

Comment: Is your module sequenced after Magento's GroupedProduct module? You can quickly check the order by looking at app/etc/config.xml to confirm your module is listed after the core one. If not Magento itself has a preference on this file in app/code/Magento/GroupedProduct/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Comment: I checked the app/etc/config.xml. and it's  not after the Magento's GroupedProduct module. I changed the my module's namespace to start with 'N', so it'll be load after the Magento's GroupedProduct module. Then it works. I think this is the issue. Thanks for pointing out. How can I load My module after the Magento's GroupedProduct without changing the namespace?

Comment: @Kristof at Fooman : Many thanks for pointing the issue. It worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the file `app/code/Best/CustomGrouped/etc/module.xml` to load my custom module after the core module worked for me.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Best_customGrouped" setup_version="0.0.1" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_GroupedProduct"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

The issue was sine the namespace of My custom module started with letter 'B' it was listed before the Magento's GroupedProduct module in `app/etc/config.xml`. So I force my module to load after the Magento's one by using above code.

> A very big thank for @Kristof at Fooman for pointing me the issue.

Comment: i have done same but not working "500" error display on screen.